# MySQL SELECT .. WHERE .. ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1000000,10 performance

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance

I have following Innodb table with ~2.500.000 rows:

`ID | param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 | sort_field1 | sort_field2 | sort_field3 | sort_field4`

```
ID - int, PK
param1-4 - tinyint(1), INDEX (it has only 0 OR 1 value)
sort_field1-4 - int, INDEX (it could be any number in INT range)
```

Each param(1-4) has value distrubution about 40% of 0 and 60% of 1.

I am trying to optimize fetching rows from the middle-end of table in this super simple query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE param1=0 ORDER BY sort_field1 LIMIT 1000000,10
```

It took about 1.7sec to fetch 10 rows and EXPLAIN show that only param1 index is being used.

I can create index (param1,sort_field1) and it will reduce time to 0.17sec, but i can't create indexes for each and every combination of params and sort_field.

Is it possible to optimize this query and/or table to achieve time similar to one i got with combined index?

Comment: This is a question for the [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions) site of the network

Comment: Fetching records far from the start is expensive operation in MySQL. And it cannot be optimized directly. For example, do you REALLY need in strictly 1000000th record and not approximately?

Comment: @Akina Yes, this is for api request backend and being able to access every row is a project requirement.

Comment: Well, if so - accept and wait. I have not seen any general method to optimize LIMIT. All of them are private, highly dependent on the task and data.

Comment: See https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/ Note that any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing - but at 2.5m rows, I guess you know that already